# cellHeight: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range when pulling up data in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am creating an Event App wherein thousands of participants are listed inside `UITableView`. The process should be to `checkIn`(by tapping a button) 2 or more participants and pull to refresh. Pull to refresh executes successfully, but when I tried pulling/scrolling up the data, it crashes and appears `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` . Hope you could help because I tried to use the solutions in SO but still not working. Thank you.
[image: error here]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath.row]
}
```

**UIRefreshControl code**

```
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createCellHeightsArray()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ParticipantsViewController.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    ParticipantTableView.addSubview(refresher)

    countNotif()
    getData()

}

  @objc func refresh() {
    countNotif()
    getParticipants()
    refresher.endRefreshing()
    ParticipantTableView.reloadData()
   }
  func getData() {
    getParticipants()

    if let posts = participants {
        self.participants = posts
    } else {
    self.participants.removeAll()
}
    self.refresh()
}
```

**cellHeightArray**

```
  func createCellHeightsArray() {

    cellHeights.removeAll()

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        for _ in 0...filteredParticipants.count {
            cellHeights.append(kCloseCellHeight)
        }
    }else {
        for _ in 0...participants.count {
            cellHeights.append(kCloseCellHeight)
        }
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard case let cell as ParticipantCell = cell else {
        return
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        cell.participant = filteredParticipants[indexPath.row]
    }else {
        cell.participant = participants[indexPath.row]
    }

    if cellHeights[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] == kCloseCellHeight {
        cell.unfold(false, animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        cell.unfold(true, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the code you posted (other than `heightForRowAt`) is relevant to your issue. Show how your declare and populate `cellHeights`. Show how it relates to the data used in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi!, I edited by post and add the codes. Hope it could me. Thank you so much

Comment: Did you try calling `createCellHeightsArray` inside `getData()` or inside `refresh` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

`filteredParticipants.count-1` OR `0..<unsortedStrings.count`

`0...participants.count-1` OR `0..<participants.count`

```
func createCellHeightsArray() {

    cellHeights.removeAll()

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        for _ in 0..<filteredParticipants.count {
            cellHeights.append(kCloseCellHeight)
        }
    }else {
        for _ in 0..<participants.count {
            cellHeights.append(kCloseCellHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Titus don't forget to call `createCellHeightsArray()` after reloading/filtering `participants` probabily inside `getParticipants()` or where setting participants 
 list `filteredParticipants ` and/or `participants`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked when i called `createCellHeightsArray()` inside `getParticipants()`